# using text or textjoin to merge two dates into a date range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've tried everything to get two dates in two separate cells to merge into a date range field.  I need cell G4, which contains 7/15/2019 and cell G5, which contains 7/19/2019 to merge in cell G6 as 7/15/2019-7/19/2019.  Text(G4,"mm/dd/yyyy")&"-"&text(G5,"mm/dd/yyyy") doesn't work, nor does textjoin.  I'm using Excel in Office365 and have never seen anything like this.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by “```Text(G4,"mm/dd/yyyy")&"-"&text(G5,"mm/dd/yyyy")``` doesn’t work”?  What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in G6:

=G4&"-"&G5

and if the text result looks returns something like this:
43661-43665

then try formatting G4 and G5 as text

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Why do you think that would work, in light of what OP tried?

Comment: yes you are correct i should have mentioned that it worked on my end because in my test cells were formatted as text.